# Automate Extracting PDF Data Using Excel

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, powerquery, m

### Problem

I currently have a directory of PDFs containing well-structured tabular data that I want to convert to Excel. (For eventual storage in SqlServer)

### My Current Solution

In Excel - run a custom M query that pulls data from a PDF and transforms it into an Excel file.

The trouble here is that using Excel requires a human to go and click a button then wait. I have a large number of PDFs, and the current manual solution would take too long. I would like to automate it end-to-end (or, in this case, directory-of-pdfs-to-excel-and-database). Also, while the tables themselves are consistent, they may appear at different locations within the PDFs. For a human, finding the correct table is easy, but I'm not sure where in the automation process this would go.

**I would like to do this using technology already in use at my company.**

- VS/C#(dotnet core 3.1), SSMS/SqlServer, Excel, and related products.

### Questions

Is there a way to access Excel's import-pdf-data functionality in C#?
Can I use my M query from C# somehow?
Is it possible to skip Excel and import directly PDF -> SqlServer?

### My Ideal Solution

```
using somePowerQueryLibrary;
using someExcelLibrary;

private void loadExcelFromPdf(string dir, PowerQuery M_query)
{
    // ???
}

public void PdfsToDb(string dir)
{
    var M_query = PQ.fromString("My query string");
    var xl = loadExcelFromPdf(dir, M_query);

    ...
}
```

OR

```
A database function that can pull directly PDF -> MSSQL would work too.
```

Comment: It seems like you're attacking this problem all at once. I think you'll eventually solve it by breaking it in parts:
1 - Can you load a PDF using C#?  Search for libraries in that area. I doubt you'll be able to extract a table per se, but you can get the text from the PDF. PDF was not made for this task...  

2 - Can you somehow parse this text reliably into a table-like structure? If the tables all have different formatting, it's gonna be hard. Tons of automated test is required here.

3 - After parsing, just throw it in the DB.

This is gonna be very tricky though....

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look into this, at least to understand how difficult it is: https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/extract-table-data-from-pdf-documents-in-c-sharp. I don't work for that company, I never tested the product, but you can search for similar solutions.